# Displaying ConfirmDialog depends on result of method

Tags: jsf

here is my `commandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton value="Foo" update="panel1,panel2"
                    action="#{fooBean.add()}" />
```

method `fooBean.add()` is checking if object i want to add is not already in database - it return true - if it is already in base, false if it is not.

what i want to do is display a success message if `fooBean.add()` will return false after click on button.

It would be nice if that message would be like `ConfirmDialog` with `OK` option to close poped out window. Something like this:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf

Any ideas how to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you just want to display a dialog, so that the user acknowledges that the action succeeded. You could simply use a [growl](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/growl.jsf), but here is a solution using your approach.

**.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton value="Foo" action="#{fooBean.add()}" />

<p:dialog widgetVar="dialog" modal="true">
    <p:commandButton value="Ok" icon="ui-icon-close" oncomplete="dialog.hide()" /> 
</p:dialog>
```

**fooBean**

```
public void add() {

    // do stuff

    if(isInDB)
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dialog.show()");
}
```

This opens the dialog after your item has already been found in the database. Nevertheless it may be more convenient for the user if he'd get a more subtle notification, without extra clicks.